# Multiple instances v. single static instance

Tags: java, oop, memory-management, coding-style, static-members

Let's say I have this custom component. It subclasses `JMenuItem` and all instances use the same `Font` object, although none share the same instance. For example,

```
public abstract class JFooMenuItem extends JMenuItem{
    public JFooMenuItem(final String title){
        super(title);
        setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 12));
    }
}
```

Now, given that there may be up to 10+ menu items, would it be more efficient to make the `Font` instance a shared, `static` member variable, or is this current setup (i.e. the code above) just fine (memory-management-wise)?

Comment: If memory isn't really tight and this isn't a very tiny program, then this is premature optimization. The real reason for doing this would be construction time if these menu items are being created all the time.

Comment: @larsmans, Yeah..you're right. I guess I just want to get it right the first time..

Comment: @larsmans - I don't think it is a premature optimization. The debate here is: `protected Font font = new Font()` or `public static final Font font = new Font()`. I think the second option is far better in coding style.

Comment: @larsmans - Also I think `premature optimization` is used too much as an excuse of poor coding. The programmers hands won't break if he writes two more words. Premature optimization is coding some fast fancy algorithms when you have already reached a reasonable performance, and missing the deadline because of that. Writing clean code is not an optimization, it is a necessity.

Comment: @PetarMinchev: I agree that putting the `Font` in a `static final` member would be good coding style; I just want to assure the OP that their worries about memory use aren't warranted, since that's what the question is about.

Comment: beware: subclassing a JSomething for configuration is a no-go! They are meant to used, subclass only if you have to add functionality and/or bug fixes. Otherwise, use a application scope factory which vends the configured components. Alternatively, if the appearance of all somethings in the app should be the same, adding those properties to the UIManager might be an option

Comment: @kleopatra, Excellent point about using the `UIManager`; I completely forgot about that. But do all the LaFs share the same properties?

Comment: they should, at least for the base ones ;-) Nimbus is critically misbehaving, others use more or less the same keys and respect their values. Look into the code of BasicLookAndFeel (and subclasses) to get an idea. Also Rob (@camickr) has a visual uiManager property inspector somewhere in his blog

Comment: @kleopatra, Thanks for the resource recommendation. And by the way, doesn't relying on the UIManager properties make the code fragile, since those are out of my control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say use one named instance, not because of the memory, but because if you decide to change the font, you have to edit at `10+` places.

`public static final Font MENU_FONT = new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 12);`

Edit: Even if you use subclassing, better declare it as `public static final` because the `Font` is constant. It is more clear.

Comment: Actually, I would still only have to edit it in `1` place, since all the menu items will be subclassing `JFooMenuItem`...

Comment: If you are going to subclass, you will have to use again one named instance:)

Comment: @mre Even so, it could be considered a constant, so using a static final field would make sense. To be honest, I wouldn't worry much about the memory overhead. Good code style is more important and efficiency tends to follow from it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the memory overhead associated with the 10 instance of `Font` to not be an issue of real concern here. However, from a code style, your `Font` is a constant across all instances of this type, therefore I think your code would be more readable if it were treated that way.

Answer (score 0):

You code will construct a new `Font` object every time you instantiate a `JFooMenuItem`.

If you make it a static member, the `Font` is only allocated once.

Comment: That is exactly the focus of my question. Is it poor memory-management to store several similar `Font` instances vs. a single, static `Font` instance?

Comment: @mre - It is better to use one static `Font` instance - better memory management and code style.

Comment: @mre: Of course it is - they're not similar, they're identical. Why would you fill up the memory with 50 identical immutable objects?

Comment: @Eric, I didn't know if caching a static variable had a lot of memory overhead to it compared to several non-static variables..